# loop causing excel to freeze?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy contents from each variable in a collection and it freezes everytime it runs the first file

```
RecursiveDir colFiles, path, "*.xlsm", True
For Each varFile In colFiles
    lineCount = 0
    reportRow = 3
    Set reportBook = Workbooks.Open(varFile)
    Set cooSummary = reportBook.Sheets("Audit")
    Do While cooSummary.Cells(reportRow, 1) <> ""
        lineCount = lineCount + 1  
    Loop
    lineNum = lineNum + 1
    With cooSummary
         scanDate = FileDateTime(varFile)
         scanned = lineCount
         auditor = .Cells(1, 2)
    End With
    ReDim Preserve reportArray(3, lineNum)
    reportArray(0, lineNum) = scanDate
    reportArray(1, lineNum) = scanned
    reportArray(2, lineNum) = auditor
    reportRow = reportRow + 1
    reportBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
Next varFile
```

Comment: you aren't incrementing reportRow inside the loop, you are incrementing linecount so the do loop will never finish if cell(3,1) is not blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to increment `reportRow` in the do loop or it won't finish.

```
Do While cooSummary.Cells(reportRow, 1) <> ""
    lineCount = lineCount + 1  
    reportRow = reportRow + 1
Loop
```